# How to match a fixed number of characters in ANTLR 3?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3

I want to parse ISO 8601 dates in my ANTLR grammar.

```
2001-05-03
```

I have the following entries in my grammar file:

```
date    : FOUR_DIGIT ('-')? TWO_DIGIT ('-')? TWO_DIGIT ;

FOUR_DIGIT
    : TWO_DIGIT TWO_DIGIT ; 

TWO_DIGIT
    : DIGIT DIGIT ;

DIGIT   : ('0'..'9') ;
```

I know I can match one or more with `DIGIT+` and zero or more with `DIGIT*`

While this works, is there a simpler syntax to specify I want to match exactly 2 `DIGIT`?

Comment: just for those that drive by in the future, I abandoned parsing dates in my parser and decided it is better to parse the dates directly in code until I can figure out a way to parse dates natively that doesn't end up conflicting with other terms that start with `DIGIT` patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure ANTLR 3 has no quantifiers besides `*`, `+` and `?`. `DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT` seems like the most reasonable way to get the behavior you want.

See http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammars

Answer (score 8):

> *Jarrod Roberson wrote:*
>
> While this works, is there a simpler syntax to specify I want to match exactly 2 DIGIT?

No, `DIGIT DIGIT` is the only way to match exactly two digits. ANTLR does **not** support something like `DIGIT{2}`, unfortunately.

Comment: I removed month, it didn't buy me anything, since it collides with trying to restrict the days as the same way. Also `00` would not be a valid month.

Comment: I see. Yes, that looks better: just match the dates "loosely" and at a later stage check if it's a valid date or not.

Comment: Perhaps you know, but realize that all 4 (and 2) digit numbers are now tokenized as FOUR_DIGIT (or TWO_DIGIT). So calling DIGIT+ from any of your parser rules can never match either four- or two successive digits.

Comment: @Jarrod, yeah, I figured that much, but wanted to make sure.